# Jovo, I need to use tell without ending the session

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, alexa-skills-kit, jovo-framework

I have saved a session attribute:

```
context.setSessionAttribute('RadioName', radioFound);
```

And I have used it to search for a the variable "result" in another intent this way:

```
 context.alexaSkill().audioPlayer().play(result, 'First song').tell("I will play your radio");
```

I still need to use the same attribute radioName in another intent. But, since "tell" ends the session. This seems to be impossible.
Using ask instead of tell reasonably doesn't work since the audioplayer won't work.
Is there any way to go around this issue?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Audioplayer responses do not keep the session open, so it is not possible to save data in session attributes.

I recommend to persist data in a database like this:

```
this.user().data.radioName = radioFound;
```

For this, you need to set up a database. A local file is used by default for local prototyping. For AWS Lambda, we recommend DynamoDB.

Learn more here:

- Jovo User Class: https://www.jovo.tech/docs/data/user#user-data
- Jovo Database Integrations: https://www.jovo.tech/docs/databases

Comment: does ending the session mean that alexa exits the skill completely?

Comment: it means that the mic is not open anymore, so you need to say "Alexa, ..." again to invoke it